# Scrapy crawls but doesn't compare to file and returns null

Tags: python, scrapy

This spider is made with the idea of comparing a list of keywords from a file with text from a page and extract strings / paragraphs.

Given the next spider:

```
import scrapy
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

class StringGrab(scrapy.Spider):
name = "stringpage"
start_urls = [
    'https://whatscookingamerica.net/Glossary/A.htm',

]

def parse(self, response):

    in_file = tuple(open("dictionarA1.csv", "r"))

    for word in in_file:
        for para_text in response.xpath(u'//p/text()[contains(..,"{0}")]'.format(word)).extract():        
            yield {
                'dictA': para_text,
            }

custom_settings = {
    "DOWNLOAD_DELAY": 1,
    "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN": 10
}
```

My question is like in the title, the spider crawls, shows the code `200` for every link (if more are added) but it doesn't give any output in a csv file.

Edit:

If I introduce a keyword in the search and extract, it works

```
'dictA0': word.xpath('//p/text()[contains(..,"a la")]').extract(),
'dictA1':  word.xpath('//p/text()[contains(..,"a la Anglaise")]').extract(),
```

thus extracting and writing in a file any paragraph that contains "a la" and " a la Anglaise".

Comment: Where are you writing the file?

Comment: `scrapy crawl stringpage -o dict.csv` command. @MaximilianPeters

Comment: Have you checked if your selector does really extract anything? No idea what your words are, but I would suggest checking out the site in the shell : `scrapy shell {your_url}` and then use your selector.

Comment: In this instance, the words are the bolded ones from the webpage. I will try it asap and I'll be back with answers / more questions.

Comment: @rongon The selector works, it extracts what I need if I introduce it by hand like this `'dictA0': link.xpath('//p/text()[contains(..,"a la")]').extract(),
             'dictA1':  link.xpath('//p/text()[contains(..,"a la Anglaise")]').extract(), `

Comment: Are you sure that your file is read correctly then? Without knowing your source file, I'd guess that maybe when iterating over the file, the `word`s are somehow different than expected.

Comment: It reads the file if I print `word` it prints the word/words added to the file. So there is no problem there.